# Repeat calculations for every row of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The following calculations were for the 1st row, i.e., `train_df.y1[0]`.

I want to repeat this operation for all 400 rows of `train_df`

```
squared_deviations_y1_0_train = ((ideal_df.loc[:0,"y1":"y50"] - train_df.y1[0]) ** 2).sum(axis=1)
```

The result is correct, just need to repeat it.

Comment: Use `.apply()` to call a function on every row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your end result seems to be a scalar, you can convert both of these dataframes to Numpy and take advantage of braodcasting.

Something like this,

```
squared_deviations = ((ideal_df.to_numpy() - train_df.y1.to_numpy().reshape(-1,1)) ** 2).sum(axis=1)
```

would do pretty nicely. If you MUST stay within pandas, you could use the `subtract()` method to get the same outcome.

```
(train_df.y1.subtract(ideal_df.T) ** 2).sum(axis=0)
```

Not that train_df.y1 becomes a row vector of size (400,) so you need to make the row dimension 400 to do this subtraction (hence the transpose of ideal_df).

You can also use the `apply()` method as Barmar suggested. This will require you to define a function that calculates the row index so that you can subtract the appropriate value of train_df for every cell before you perform the square and sum operations. Something like this,

```
(ideal_df.apply(lambda cell: cell - train_df.y1[cell.index]) ** 2).sum(axis=1)
```

would also work. I highly recommend using Numpy for these tasks because Numpy was designed with broadcasting in mind, but as shown you can get away with doing it in Pandas.

Comment: thank you! I actually was mistaken and what I needed wasn't the sum of the columns on every row but the sum of every row on every column, so I need to expand this to all 400 rows :`squared_deviations_y1_0_train = ((ideal_df.loc[:0,"y1":"y50"] - train_df.y1[0]) ** 2)` . I'm trying the apply method you mentioned but I'm getting errors. Will keep trying

Comment: never mind I actually got it right. You helped me a lot. Thanks!

Comment: If you're allowed to, could you verify that the answer was correct by leaving an upvote? It will let me write comments on other posts going forward.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't, I tried at the time. "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded. "